# How to make import os command work in python script

Tags: python, vector, import

I have a python script named as `classify_images.py` and i execute this script will go inside image directory to handle image and create `image_vectors` file, i want to ask if i want to execute this `classify_image.py` in new python scripts, what should i do? I have use `os.system` command in the new python scripts like

```
import os
os.system('python classify_images.py "images/*"')
```

but it won't work, it only show results in the command prompt and do not create the `image_vector` folder. But i use the command ipython `classify_images.py "images/*"` and it works perfectly in Jupyter notebook. I search website, some python user say directly use import but I don't have any idea how to import classify.py script that need to access the image folder inside directory and I am an anaconda spyder user. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The current working folder (`os.getcwd()`) is important when you need to manipulate items on your os.  If you added a `print(os.getcwd())` in your script you might notice that it returns a different path depends where you execute the python interpreter.  I'd wager it is creating the folders alright, just not where you expected it.

The solution is either use an absolute path for your folder creation (e.g. `"C:/Users/YourName/SomePath/image vectors"`) or change your working directory with `os.chdir(parent_path_where_folder_should_be_created)` before you create a folder with relative path.

If you give more information about the relevant part of your script that creates the folder as well as how and *where* you call `os.system('python...')`, I could possibly comment on what is necessary to change.

Comment: I execute all in the same directory

Comment: Then you will have to give us a bit more information to go on.  What is the [MCVE] content of `classify_images.py`?

Comment: Thank Idelehand, i copy the whole address in my python code and it solve